# How to send a result to next Activity after finish()?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to send a madeObject from Start_Activity to Next_Activity after finishing Start_Activity. 
How to make a code in Start_Activity and Next_Activity?

My sequence is : 
 
1) Start_Activity.onCreate() 
2) Start_Activity.makeObjectData() 
3) Start_Activity.putextras(madeObject) 
3) Start_Activity.startActivity() : start Next_Activity. 
4) Start_Activity.finish() : finish Start_Activity

5) Next_Activity.getExtras()

Here is Start_Activity

```
public class Start_Activity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_launching_activity);
                  :
        //// makeDataObject ///
                  :
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Next_Activity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(madeDataObject);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

This is Next_Activity

```
public class Next_Activity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.a_launching_activity);
        ??? <-- How to get the madeDataObject of Start_Activity?
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `getIntent().getSerializableExtra("key");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bundle.putSerializable` takes two parameters. The first is a String. It has to be unique for this bundle object. You will use it afterwards, to retrieve your object.

```
bundle.putSerializable("my_unique_key", madeDataObject);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

on `Next_Activity`, you can retrieve the intent with `getIntent()`

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
  if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
    intent.getExtras().getSerializable("my_unique_key");
  }
```

Of course the object you are trying to pass from one activity to another has to implements Serializable

Comment: Um.. Start_Activity have to be finished.   Is it possible to use getIntent() after finishing Start_Activity?

Comment: yes, because the Intent is maintained by the system and is kept for the second Activity throughout, although if you end the StartActivity and give the activity as a context I think that would prevent it from using the GC so create the intent using `getApplicationContext()` instead.

Answer (score -1):

send extras to next activity as:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Next_Activity.class);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("myclass", madeDataObject);
        intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
```

Get it in next activity like:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
    intent.getExtras().getSerializable("myclass");
  }
```